# Is there any way to conditionally ignore a test with JUnit of Spring?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an integration test that fetches from a 3rd party API, I'd like to only run this test class manually, is there any way I can ignore the test unless an argument/parameter/env variables is passed? So I can run the test manually with my IDE, but have CI ignore it.

Worth saying that I have unit tests that test smaller portions of the workload that can always run.

Comment: perhaps http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/01/separating-integration-tests-from-unit-tests-using-maven-failsafe-junit-category.html can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Junit [`Assume`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html):

```
public class SomeTest {
    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        Assume.assumeTrue("someValue".equals(System.getProperty("some.property")));
    }

    // add your @Test
}
```

You could also use [`@IfProfileValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html) for tests using spring junit runner